# Viewing contents of a script fed into a shell via STDIN

Tags: shell-script

I am investigating something. I have a `/bin/sh` (it is `dash` in this case) process which runs a script fed into shell's `STDIN`. Something else launches (daemonizes) this process and I would like to know what this process does and what that script looks like.

For example, if you submit the following into the shell

```
echo 'echo ONE; sleep 99; sleep 666; echo TWO' | /bin/sh
```

in the process list at any point in time you can only see the command being executed at the moment (e.g. `sleep 99`) but not the whole script.

How can I recover the contents of the whole script?

P.S. The focus of this question is not to find a way to tell who/what launches the script or why I need it, etc.

Comment: is your `/bin/sh` Bash or something else? (See what `/bin/sh --version` prints?)

Comment: Assuming you can't get in the "middle" of where the shell is launched (to do something like adding `-x` to the command line), you could try setting the `ENV` or `BASH_ENV` envvars to point to some script (assuming your `sh` reads those on all invocations), or if nothing else, replace `/bin/sh` with something that copies the output to stdout too. Though that would be a rather invasive operation for the rest of the system too, but at least on Linux, you could alleviate that by using mount namespaces to do a private mount over `/bin/sh` for that process only

Comment: Just to clarify; You wrote: _Something else launches this process ..._; You don't know what is this "something else"? Is that what you want to find out? Is it something that runs periodically? A cron, or system service or something? Is this `sh` processes running all the time in the background, or it just runs as one-off shots?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Linux, you could use `bpftrace` to report what `sh` processes read from stdin:

```c
#! /usr/bin/env bpftrace
tracepoint:syscalls:sys_enter_read /comm == "sh"/ {
  /*
   * Upon read(2) syscall entry, record whether the read() is on fd 0 (stdin)
   * and if yes, where the read goes on a per-task basis
   */
  @from_stdin[tid] = (args->fd == 0);
  if (@from_stdin[tid]) {
    @addr[tid] = args->buf;
  }
}
tracepoint:syscalls:sys_exit_read /
  comm == "sh" &&
  @from_stdin[tid] &&
  args->ret > 0
/ {
  printf(
    "sh process %d read %d bytes from stdin: \"%r\"\n",
                tid,
                        args->ret,
                                               buf(@addr[tid], args->ret)
  );
}
```

Then running `echo 'echo foo | cat' | sh` will show in the output of that `bpftrace` script:

```
$ sudo ./that-bpftrace-script
./that-script:13:16-18: WARNING: Addrspace mismatch
  comm == "sh" &&
               ~~
Attaching 2 probes...
sh process 83359 read 15 bytes from stdin: "echo foo | cat\x0a"
```

(I don't know what the *Addrspace mismatch* warning is about but it seems harmless; you can suppress it along with the *Attaching 2 probes...* with `-q --no-warning`).

Comment: This is great. How would I trigger the tracing, just by executing the 1st bpftrace script? How would I stop the tracing? Sorry, I had never dealt with bpftrace before.

Comment: @oᴉɹǝɥɔ, you just run that bpftrace script as root, and then wait for that `sh` command to be run. Ctrl+C to stop the bpftrace script.

Answer (score 2):

You could try hijacking the shell but this is fraught with potential complications, and most importantly perhaps I have not tested this at all well.

1. Move the shell from `/bin/sh` to `/bin/sh.bin`
2. Create a script called `/bin/sh` that captures *stdin* to a file and then invokes `/bin/sh.bin` to run it
3. Remember to ensure the script is executable and that it uses `/bin/sh.bin`

The script might look something like this

```
#!/bin/sh.bin

# If it looks interactive run the real shell directly
[ -t 0 ] && exec /bin/sh.bin "$@"

# Otherwise grab stdin and then execute it
tee /tmp/sh_stdin.$$ | /bin/sh.bin "$@"
```

Make sure you have a different shell open in a root window somewhere. For example, `sudo bash`, and do not close that session until you have either confirmed that the script hackery works *and* that you have reverted the changes.

Comment: This seems like a viable approach